# Salesforce Managed Package Install Failure

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have updated my managed package - going from beta 14 to beta 15.  The 14 previous versions all worked just fine.  I am able to upload without problem and an install link is generated.  However, when I try to install the beta in a separate developer org, I get the following message (i'd call it an error but there is no detail at all suggest whether it is an error or not):

> Your requested install failed. Please try this again.
>
> None of the data or setup information in your salesforce.com
>   organization should have been affected by this error.
>
> If this error persists, contact salesforce.com Support through your
>   normal channels and reference number: 35557683-12022 (1510032338)

I've submitted a ticket with SFDC support, but since I'm not a premier customer, they say it will take 2 days to get back to me.  Does anyone no how to dig into this?  Is there a log file somewhere that I can look at that will indicate what the problem is?  Thanks in advance you can provide any guidance.

Comment: Did the other 14 betas install on another developer account fine?

Comment: Yup, they worked just fine.  It was about a month between 14 and 15 though and a good bit of code change.

Comment: So to followup on this issue, I did hear back from SF support and they were definitely polite if not particularly helpful.  At this point, my issue has been escalated to "R&D".  In the meantime, I moved my code to a separate org altogether, then deployed to a brand new build org.  This took some time because I wanted to make sure that there were no unused static resources or files included.  Sure enough, I was able to build and install a managed package this way.  I think there may be a bug of some sort in the managed package process - I will post again if I head from support with a resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got confirmation from Salesforce Support today that if you have a static resource named "x" or "c", then the process that builds the package will not see the resource.  This was exactly my experience.  In addition, it would not let me remove the static resource I had named "x" even after removing all references to it in my code.

To resolve I had to move all of my code (minus the static resource named "x") to a new dev org, and deploy from there.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the joys of Salesforce support. I hope you have plenty of patience, you're going to need it.

What you are receiving is an internal exception. The details are purposely unavailable, thus making it harder for nasty people to exploit the system.

What it means is you have no choice but to wait 2 days, but don't expect an answer in 2 days. You'll get a reply asking for admin access or something else. Then maybe your case will get escalated. Then eventually someone will be able to give you some details.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - The strange thing is that if I push my code to a different org and build it as an unmanaged package, it seems to work just fine, but once I convert it to managed, it will not install again.